# slope from an extruded curve object

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, vertices, extrude, displacement

I'm trying to slope a curve object. I hope to be able to control the angle because the dimensions matter.
So if I were doing this with a displacement map, it would be something like this [image] When I try to move the points along the z nothing happens.

Here is my file https://blend-exchange.com/b/WpLDDqal

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to rotate around an axis that would be on the left side of your figure ? Or do you want to increase linearly the Z coordinate from left to right (so from top view, the shape will remained unaffected) ?

Comment: Do you want to use the object mode editor and the mouse ? Are you open to use modifiers ? Are you open to use Geometry Nodes ?

Comment: Yes I am hoping to leave the outer shape unaffected. I am hoping to turn this into a physical object so the cleanest way it can be done would be best. Using displacement modifiers caused banding. Thank you!

Comment: Convert your curve to mesh extrude the surface and use  the Shear tool on the extruded part.

Answer (score 1):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

[image: Rotate 2D curve]

The Z coordinate can not be modified because the shape of the curve is *2D*. And it has to remain 2D to fill upper and lower surfaces.

**Procedure:** Add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to the curve object. As the *Geometry* from the *Group Input* node is already a *Mesh*, there is no need to add a *Curve to Mesh* node. A *Transform Geometry* node is inserted between input and output to apply a rotation around Y axis. As shown in top left inserted picture, control points are still available in *Edit Mode* to modify the curve.